# dijit FilteringSelect disable item click event

Tags: dojo

I made some improvements on the filteringselect so it would accept checkbox inputs that will enable me to choose multiple values with the widget.
there is only one thing I couldn't solve.
when selecting any item of the dropdown options, the dropdown closes.
that is expected behavior but I need to cancel the "closeDropDown" method because the purpose is to choose as many items as I need.
how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override the closeDropDown method in your custom widget, and do nothing...

e.g. :

```
require([
    'dojo/_base/declare', 
    'dijit/popup',
    'dijit/form/FilteringSelect', 
    'dojo/domReady!'
], function (declare, popup, FilteringSelect) {

    var CustomFilteringSelect = declare([FilteringSelect], {
        closeDropDown : function(/* Boolean */ focus){
            console.log("Not closing");
        },

        postCreate : function(){
            this.inherited(arguments);
            this.on("blur",  function(){
                if(this._opened){
                    this._popupStateNode.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
                    if(focus){
                        this.focus();
                    }
                    popup.close(this.dropDown);
                    this._opened = false;
                }
            });
        }
    });


    var select = new CustomFilteringSelect(someprops, somenode);
    select.startup();
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/72HKG/ for an example.

Comment: well, this helps to not closing the dropdown but I need to close it when the FilteringSelect is Blured, so how to tell the dropdown to close just on blur but not on click?

Comment: See my updated response. I just put the code previously in closeDropDown into the onblur event handler...

Comment: I see. but I checked this solution on http://jsfiddle.net/7K3qZ/ but says "popup is not defined"

Comment: I had forgotten the popup module in the dependencies. Check http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/72HKG/ again.